# change background color given word in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to change the background color of all pages with /cutticket in the URL using jquery.

Right now I have the following but I am not seeing any visible change. No console errors at the moment.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("/cutticket") > -1) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: just do document.body.style.background="red";

Comment: Your code works, @rs19.

Comment: Where do you have that code? It should be after the DOM has loaded (i.e., in document.ready or in a `<script>` tag at the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: `console.log(window.location.href.indexOf("/cutticket"));` Do you see what you expect? Is the code in the head or the body?

Comment: @epascarello when i run in the console it returns 24, the position in the url https://loosethreads.xyz/cutticket

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you :-)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if( location.href.indexOf('/cutticket') > -1 ){
    $('body').css('background-color','red');
  }
});
```

As others have mentioned you should place this code, if its embedded onto the html file above these tags.

```
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit:

Give this a try instead:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   if (window.location.href.indexOf("/cutticket") > -1) {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
});
```

This uses a vanilla javascript approach to wait for the dom to load for you then run the commands.

**Edit 2**

The following code should work to achieve what you are looking to do on your site:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if( location.href.indexOf('/cutticket') > -1 ){
    $('#canvas-wrapper').css('background-color','red');
  }
});
```

**Reason**
Your site has a colored div that is an overlay on the body and while it technically IS coloring the body, the wrapper element is hiding it. This will change the color of the correct element on the page for you. You can paste this code into the chrome developer console and see it work :-).

*Something else to note:* While I was on your site I noted that there is an error in JSON somewhere on your page as well as your site is loading in at least 3 copies of jQuery which could cause you some issues down the line.

Comment: so when i do that i get `m.fn.init[1]0: documentcontext: documentlength: 1__proto__: Object[0]`

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @rs19 Could you post a link to the HTML perhaps? That is an output that suggest that the jquery selector found nothing in your document called 'body' which sounds like an error in the HTML. I would be happy to take a look:-)

Comment: @rs19 Please take a look at the recent edit. place that in <script></script> tags just before your </body> tag and it should run without an issue. Let me know if that gives you any errors!

Comment: @LucasShanley thanks for your help on this. still isn't working as i hoped. here's the actual website so you can see. https://loosethreads.xyz/cutticket

Comment: @rs19 I updated the above post with a working script and i added a few notes of some things I saw in the code that you might want to look into!  Let me know if I can help out any further with this!

Comment: @rs19 Please remember to mark as answered if this has successfully answered your question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works.

Simply include:

```
<script>
if (window.location.href.indexOf("/cutticket") > -1) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

just before:

```
</body>
</html>
```

**Reason:**
The script makes a reference to `<body>` - so for the script to work properly, the browser must have parsed `<body>` in the markup before it starts parsing the script.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i just tried putting it in the footer and it still is not working. any thoughts?

Comment: My thoughts: The code you have supplied in your answer works. If it is not working in your setup then something else in your setup is stopping it from working.

Answer (score -1):

I had done it something like this:

```
<script>
    var base = "http://0.0.0.0:8881"
    var url = document.URL;
    if (!(url == base + "/asda")) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
</script>
```